# ¿Como puedo leer una contraseña por consola y reemplazarla por asteriscos en c#?

Tags: c#, consola, contraseña

Quiero crear un método por consola que lea una contraseña y mientras esta se este digitando oculte los caracteres reemplazándolos por asteriscos.
El siguiente código funciona, pero cuando la contraseña es numérica la muestra con una letra "D" antes de cada número, me gustaría solucionar este error y saber cual es la causa o razón por la cual se imprime esa D.

```
 private static void OcultarContraseña()
    {
        List<string> lstClave = new List<string>();
        do
        {
            lstClave.Add(Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).Key));
            Console.Write("*");
        } while (lstClave[lstClave.Count()-1] != Convert.ToString(ConsoleKey.Enter));
        string strDato="";

        for (int i = 0; i < lstClave.Count()-1; i++)
        {
            strDato += lstClave[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nLa contraseña es "+ strDato);
    }
```

Comment: Si, no me arroja ningún mensaje de error o excepción y funciona igual si le elimino los paréntesis del Count

Comment: Vale, vale, al copiar y pegar tu código no me pasa más que quedarme en el loop imprimiendo asteriscos, algo en especial que debamos saber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estás añadiendo a tu lista la tecla (`key`) pulsada, en lugar del caracter que corresponde a dicha tecla. Cambiando un poco tu método funcionará correctamente:

```
private static void OcultarContraseña()
{
    List<string> lstClave = new List<string>();
    while (true)
    {
        var tecla = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            break;
        }
        lstClave.Add(Convert.ToString(tecla.KeyChar));
        Console.Write("*");
    } 
    string strDato = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < lstClave.Count(); i++)
    {
        strDato += lstClave[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nLa contraseña es " + strDato);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Básicamente, hacemos un bucle infinito, del que solo se sale pulsando enter. Una vez comprobamos que no es enter, añadimos a la lista de caracteres pulsados el caracter(`KeyChar`), en lugar de la tecla (`Key`).

**Edit**

Ya que estamos, yo le añadiría el control del retorno de carro a tu método, para que se puedan borrar caracteres, algo asi:

```
private static void OcultarContraseña()
{
    List<string> lstClave = new List<string>();
    while (true)
    {
        var tecla = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            break;
        }

        else if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (lstClave.Count() > 0)
            {
                lstClave.RemoveAt(lstClave.Count - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lstClave.Add(Convert.ToString(tecla.KeyChar));
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    } 
    string strDato = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < lstClave.Count(); i++)
    {
        strDato += lstClave[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nLa contraseña es " + strDato);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Como ves, se controla si se ha pulsado `Backspace`, y en ese caso se elimina el ultimo caracter de la lista de caracteres pulsados, y se borra un asterisco de la pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en que estas haciendo un `List` de `string`, cuando deberías hacer un `List` de `char`, ya que únicamente estas guardando un carácter cada vez.

Cambiándolo solucionarías el problema:

```
private static void OcultarContraseña(){            
        List<char> lstClave = new List<char>();
        do
        {
            lstClave.Add(Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey(true).Key));
            Console.Write("*");
        } while (lstClave[lstClave.Count() - 1] != Convert.ToChar(ConsoleKey.Enter));
        string strDato = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < lstClave.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            strDato += lstClave[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nLa contraseña es " + strDato);
}
```

Comment: No tiene nada que ver, realmente... el op está convirtiendo explicitamente a `string` el código de la tecla que presiona...

Comment: Si ingreso 123 me dice que mi contraseña es abc

Comment: Has visto este enlace [Password masking console application] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404421/password-masking-console-application)